# How do I add a Windows 2003 Domain Controller to a Windows 2000 Forest?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server-2000

I currently have a Windows 2000 Active Directory and Domain.  I want to move to 2008 but I believe I have to go to 2003 first.

1. I thought the best way to start was to add the 2003 server as a domain controller in the existing forest.
2. Run adprep forestprep to bring the domain to 2003 functionality

I've seen several article, including on here.  Apparently, if I just want to add a 2003 server as a domain controller I run dcpromo.  But then I'm still at 2000 AD level.

Since the goal is to move to 2003, then 2008, should I just run adprep and forestprep on the win2k domain controller and then use dcpromo on 2003?  Or should I just run dcpromo on the 2003 server and then use adprep and forestprep on the windows 2000 server?

What's the best way to do this?  Thanks.

update:  do you think this would work with going from 2000 to 2008?

[Replace 2000 domain controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/41280/replace-2000-domain-controller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you can add a Windows 2003 or 2008 domain controller (DC) to a Windows 2000 Active Directory you need to run the `adprep /forestprep` on the forest and `adprep /domainprep` on the domain in the forest where you'll be adding the new DC. A review of [Microsoft's documentation of the process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753437(WS.10).aspx) is probably in order before you start.

You do not need to install any Windows 2003 DCs prior to installing a Windows 2008 DC. You need only prepare the AD with `adprep`. Once you've done that you can begin to promote W2K8 DCs.

Comment: but after I do that do I run dcpromo on the 2003 server?  That's where I'm confused.  Don't I have to have a 2003 DC before I do this?  I read on here SF, that you can just have a 2003 DC without the adprep.

Comment: @johnny: You owe it to yourself to read the Microsoft documentation. It describes the process and the pre-migration concerns. Since this is an operation that you can't back off once you've completed it you need to be sure that you're all ready before you begin. You don't need to use a Windows 2003-based DC to upgrade your domain to Windows 2008.

Comment: you can go straight from windows 2000 to 2008?  OH I see the title in the article.  Thanks.